# flux through the hole of annular superconductor under magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity

Let's take an annular superconductor of thickness $t$ with total radius $R_t$ and hole radius $R_h$ such that the superconductor exists in the region between radii from $R_h$ to $R_t$.

Now, if I apply a uniform external magnetic field $B$ in the plane perpendicular to the plane of the annulus, we know the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect) leads to expulsion of the magnetic field $B$ from inside the superconductor. But because of the topology of the annulus, does the Meissner effect also lead to exponentially small* flux through the hole? Or, is there a calculation/reference that works out how the flux in the hole depends on the parameters $R_h$, $R_t$, $t$ and $B$?

*By exponentially small, I mean exponentially small in the ratio of $R_t/R_h$ or $t/R_h$, such that for $t \gg R_h$ and $R_t \gg R_h$, there will be a very small flux in the hole.

Comment: This question is completely unclear to me, do you want details about the flux pinned inside the hole (called a fluxoid, or flux quantum, check wikipedia) or in the thin layer in the metallic phase which is not superconducting because of the Meissner effect (in which case this give the self-inductance of the loop in this normal region) ? A figure might greatly help understanding this question as well.